# MPMoviePlayerController seeking to beginning weird behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-streaming

I have `MPMoviePlayerController`-obj that play a hls stream from my video server. Segment duration is set to 3 seconds.

Because of the stream's video content is transcode on the fly so when user seek to a certain position, server need few seconds to seek in original movie file and start generate proper .ts files. The problem occurs if i seek the player's head to start point. After drag and release the head at **0:00**, the player send request for the first .ts file (checked by wireshark), and start playing as soon as it receives first response .ts file normally except play time is not 0:00 (the value is different in each test).

What probably the reason here?

UPDATE #1:

Content of .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:3,
http://192.168.0.68:20655/_hls_file?file=20130220155224176_00000.ts
#EXTINF:3,
http://192.168.0.68:20655/_hls_file?file=20130220155224176_00001.ts
....
#EXTINF:3,
http://192.168.0.68:20655/_hls_file?file=20130220155224176_00469.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

The actual duration  of the .ts file usually differ from target duration (3seconds), but i dont think that the reason.

UDPATE #2:

I did create VOD HTTP Stream with 10s target duration, but the player behaves in the same way. If i seek to 00:00:00, it always start playing from second 5 or 3, So i guess the reason is not from my server.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .ts file your server is responding with?

Comment: you meant .m3u8 file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the playlist file